# macOS High Sierra Turkish Keyboard Issue

Tags: macos, keyboard

I started to use a Mac mini with Turkish keyboard. However, macOS High Sierra has only Turkish Q and Turkish Q Legacy keyboard options. If I remember correctly almost one year ago I was using a MacBook in a virtual machine and when I chose to **Turkish QWERTY PC option**, every key was working as I expected. This option was removed now I think. And some keys and combination of keys don't work or represent totally different charters or symbols.

I tried to change my location but it didn't help me at all.

How can I fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Turkish Q keyboard is still in options.

Comment: Did you try both of the options?

Comment: Yes I tried both of the options. Turkish Q is %90 percent is match, however some charcters like  < > is in wrong place also some charcters like " is not shown at all.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201794 in this link, Turkey - (TQ) the keyword with numeric keypad is the exactly same as my keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmo92a6ryk8g5l1/Turkish%20QWERTY%20PC%20copy.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is a copy I made of my Turkish QWERTY PC layout from El Capitan in case that helps.

If <> is on the topmost leftmost key instead of next to the left shift, you may have a [Keyboard Type Problem](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html), where your machine thinks the keyboard is ANSI instead of ISO.  The link suggests some possible fixes.

Comment: Thank you but your copy is the exact same the Turkish Q keyboard layout in my system. Nothing changed.

Comment: @blocker so you probably have the other problem I mentioned, wrong keyboard type, right?

Comment: Yes definitely. Actually, I rented a mac mini on macincloud.com but their service is terrible. They tend not to help with this issue. I am not allowed to change keyboard type. I don't know why they don't change my keyboard type from ANSI to ISO. Anyway, here is the lesson for today: Don't use macincloud.com. They are not changing even small features in their system.

Comment: @blocker so you are talking about a mini you are using by remote access from a pc?  You really need to state that in your question, it is a totally different situation

Comment: It is totally the same situation. I talked with Apple and they say that "you need to change your keyboard type to ISO". But macincloud.com doesn't allow me to do that because of their great(!) and **very very limited** service.

Comment: Will they let you add a custom keyboard layout?  If so, that would let you move characters around.

Comment: If you are able to do, can you make a keyboard layout for me? I mean the only problem is my <> key doesn't work at all (it is a dead key I think) and my " key represents <> instead of ".  So I am not able to use " in my keyboard now. Can you make a layout for that? I am just asking.

Comment: Try this one.  <> is on option 1 and option shift 1, " is on option 5.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsvng1s4087u8if/Turkish%20QWERTY%20PC%20mod.keylayout.zip?dl=0